# Group the values that are the same in one column then add the values together from another column

Tags: sql-server-2012, sum

How can I make a query for the following:
Table Named Tags: Column named: Job_Number, Qty

```
Job_Number | Qty
-------------------------
10         |  1
12         |  2
12         |  2
10         |  3
11         |  22
12         |  1
10         |  5
12         |  4
```

Where my results would look like

```
Job_Number | Total_Qty
-------------------------
10         |  9
11         |  22
12         |  9
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic aggregation...

```
Select
    Job_Number,
    SUM(convert(int,isnull(Qty,0))) as Total_Qty
From Tags
Group by Job_Number
```

Comment: Thanks you  I hade to change the data type in my Qty Column then it worked.

Comment: No problem @BenRoland i added that edit to the answer as well